# Python Pie chart using CSV

Tags: python

I am trying to create a pie chart in python using csv file but get this error

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

Can someone please help. I need the pie chart of diagnosis column csv file.

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: What does `print(plt.pie)` show?

Comment: something to do with the value of y, can you print it out, `y = df['diagnosis'].values`

Comment: Please DO NOT paste pictures with code but enter the code itself into the question.

Comment: I think your colors input should be a list of the same length as y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are passing whole column `diagnosis` into the pie chart but it expects only statistical part of it for ex. How many M and B are there to plot. So you need to group this data to calculate stats and use that to create pie chart.

For ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('breastcancerdata.csv')
colors = ["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e"]

group_by_diag = df.groupby("diagnosis").count().reset_index()
sizes = group_by_diag['id']
labels = group_by_diag['diagnosis']

plt.pie(sizes, labels = labels, colors = colors)
plt.show()
```